# Java - From a String Type name how to initialize an ArrayList of that Type

Tags: java, generics, collections

May be many of you have several times wanted to do this. Right now I am trying to do it but stuck.

Say, I have a method like this:

```
private Object getList(String nameofType) {
  return new ArrayList<Type>(); 
/**e.g. It returns ArrayList<java.lang.Double> if nameofType is "java.lang.Double", 
/*ArrayList<java.io.File> if nameofType is "java.io.File"**/
}
```

How can I init an ArrayList like this?

Comment: We have _type erasure_ in Java when dealing with generics. That means that the parameter type of the generic type is not known at runtime. As a consequence, a `List<Double>` and a `List<File>` are the same. No need to have a string-typed method parameter for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want to do, might be this:

```
private List getList(String nameofType) {
    List list = null;
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(nameofType); //must be fully qualified, example: "java.lang.Integer"
        list = Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList(), clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // log exception, etc.
    }
    return list;
}
```

This will return an effectively type-checked list, that will throw an exception if you try to insert an object of different type than specified.
You can check it four yourself:

```
    List list = getList("java.lang.Integer");
    System.out.println("Inserting Integer");
    list.add(new Integer(1));
    System.out.println("List: "+ list);
    System.out.println("Inserting Long");
    list.add(new Long(1));
    System.out.println("List: "+ list);
```

Output:

```
Inserting Integer
List: [1]
Inserting Long
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Attempt to insert class java.lang.Long element into collection with element type class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: But of course, you can’t assign the result to an `ArrayList` anymore…

Comment: @Holger I think it is a good practice to declare your lists using the interface `List myList`; that way you can use whatever list flavor you want (LinkedList, ArrayList or even a Vector) and change it without having to retrofit a lot of code. If you absolutely need to, you could always cast to `(ArrayList)`, but at least it's not returning an `Object` like the given example.

Answer (score 2):

*(This doesn't really answer the question; it is just pointing out that a `Class<T>` parameter is unnecessary simply to create a generic list, as suggested in other answers)*

Guava's `Lists.newArrayList` method looks something like this:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> newArrayList() {
  return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

No type parameter is needed.

```
List<String> stringList = Lists.newArrayList();
List<Integer> integerList = Lists.newArrayList();
```

If you need to invoke for a specific type, you can invoke like:

```
Lists.<MySpecificType>newArrayList();
```

Comment: There you go with the problem. I am using reflection to write a generic utility. I need to populate a Bean's ArrayList type attribute by invoking its setter method. Since the List is ArrayList<String>, its setter method is essentially expecting a ArrayList<String>. Now I am dynamically trying to init a ArrayList<String> and set it to the bean. When you say type erasure is the savior, does it mean, I don't need to bother for this scenario as well? I mean, can I create a new ArrayList and pass it as parameter to the method using Reflection?

Comment: @sribasu: just make sure that your `List` doesn’t contain anything other than `String`s…

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a String-Parameter?

If not, you can use Generics:

```
private <T> Object getList(Class<T> listType) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this code satisfies your needs i believe

```
public  <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

It returns a properly `List<T>` based on the class you pass to its parameter.

Using a string as a parameter does not really help the compiler. Keep in mind that the type information for parameterised types (using generics) are erased at run-time (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: doesnt the declared type do that?

Comment: When you pass a `Class<Foo>`, then `T` is bound to `Foo`

Comment: When you don’t pass `Class<Foo>` (e.g. pass `null` or just remove the parameter), but assign the result to a variable of type `List<Foo>`, `T` still is bound to `Foo`…

Comment: Yes, but he from his requirements i understood he has "some value" that needs to determine the boundary of `T`. I otherwise would not understand what OP needs (it is all about compile time check - tbh i am having a hard time understanding  what OP really needs ). Just saw @walen answer..that's probably what he needs.